# Robobrowser developer code throws error 'object is not subscriptable'?

Tags: python, forms, screen-scraping, robobrowser

So I am getting this error... I went back to the documentation and found similar code from the developers. I copied and pasted that and it threw the same error.

Heres the code from the developer. What has changed??
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

# Browse to Rap Genius
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('http://rapgenius.com/')

# Search for Queen
form = browser.get_form(action='/search')
form                # <RoboForm q=>
form['q'].value = 'queen'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

thanks

... I've figured out that basically you cannot specify a specific form through an identifier... have have no idea why this is.. you can get_forms and do len and iterate through, but that's not really so great. Is this working for anyone else or am I just a complete rube?

Comment: You don't let us know which lines throws error. As far as NoneType it means you're most probably  operating on None (not found) element - as well form = browser.get_form(action='/search')
form                # <RoboForm q=> << I believe this line is not valid :)
form['q'].value = 'queen'

Comment: sorry! that part didnt go through apparently       
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Python37/1.py", line 11, in <module>
    form['q'].value = 'queen'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: in python you can write something like: if not form:  or if form:... (line under), if the form will be None type then it if form condition wont run. print your form and see if it has 'q' - looks like it doesnt... you should be as well able to write element_to_change = form.get("q") and then check if its not empty

Comment: any idea what the correct syntax might be? This is the code from the documentation, so if its not right I am trully lost as a noob. Any work around would be super appreciated. Spent far too long on this already (several hours)

Comment: yes, when I print, it says 'none' ... which is really confusing because the identifiers are correct and are the same still

Comment: get yourself a decent editor, i'd recommend a pycharm - it has debugger which will show you any errors and you can step debug (read about it or watch youtube vid, it will save TONS OF time). i dont think its syntax error, i just think you're pulling the wrong elements or elements that arent shown yet, try with different page and fields to see if its syntax, your usage of it or simply the website protecting itself from being scraped/automated - if i remember right q isnt it for google search lol : )

Comment: Thanks Tom. Im going to download pycharm when I can. How do you do the screenshot>? I didnt see that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Since the code we were both running is from an introductory doc page on the robobrowser website that means that robobrowser is no longer maintained.

I switched to mechanicalsoup. It is a Python module which works great and seems to be maintained (after a hiatus when it was not.) You can install it using pip.

Plus, the syntax of mechanicalsoup is simpler. For instance, you don't have to use ".value" when setting form values.

So my advice is to forget about robobrowser and switch to mechanicalsoup.